# auto height for the <object/> element with the embedded content

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to get the auto height for the `<object/>` element according to the embedded content inside. Is this possible?

An example of the issue is here: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/M4Zvc/3/). Here In Chrome, it seems the auto is ignored. How can I fix this?

**HTML**

```
<body>
    <object id="my-object" data="http://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1.txt"></object>
</body>
```

**CSS**

```
#my-object {
    height : auto;
    width : 300px;
}
```

**EDIT**
I want to make the object as big as its content, so as to avoid the scroll of object element. It should be page scroll instrad of object elements scroll.

Comment: btw, you don't have to declaire height for auto. default value of height IS auto. you try to make the object as big as the content ? so there is nothing to scroll ???

Comment: @Dwza That is my problem, I want to make the object as big as its content, so as to avoid the scroll.

Comment: Well, this isn't a good way **but** it works. If you inspect the computed style of the `object`, you'll see that it has `height:16155px` and so you can add some _fixed_ height to the `object` like 17000px to remove the scrollbar - [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/M4Zvc/9/)

Comment: @Vucko Can we make it dynamic? I mean if I want to dynamically change the data-url. How will I get the height?

Comment: Vucko just gave the answer for you if you can use JS you need to get computed height please check jQuery outerHeight if you cannot use jQuery look at Window.getComputedStyle() also look browser compatibility. The only problem is when you should get it check if object has onload/success event if it has you are pretty much done.

Comment: @OnurTOPAL outerHeight, clientHeight, innerHeight for object, all give the same height of current object tag eg 436. We cannot get computed style, as we are accessing a cross-origin frame.

Answer (score 0):

working fiddle (100% height, min-height and overflow hidden to body and html elements )

http://jsfiddle.net/DmF6B/2/

```
html, body{
   overflow:hidden;
   height: 100%;
   min-height: 100%;
}
    #my-object {
        height : 100%;
        width : 100%;
        overflow : hidden;
    }
```

html

```
<body scroll="no">
    <object id="my-object" data="http://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1.txt">
    </object>
</body>
```

Comment: try to remove it and you'll see that it doesn't work.

Comment: @faby The object's size is still not as big as content. As you can see the scroll bar appears for object. I am trying to remove that.

Comment: @faby I want to see the content as well. I mean I can see the page scroll, but I dont want the scroll for object tag.

Comment: that scroll depends on the height of the box in jsfiddle page. try it in a your page.

Comment: try now, I have updated the answer. Maybe now is what you are asking to me.

Comment: @faby, the fiddle causes a cross origin error.  Try using a local file like http://doc.jsfiddle.net/use/echo.html for the sample.

Comment: The flaw with this solution is that every tag that the <object /> is a child of needs to have the styling that is currently being applied to <html /> and <body />.  Another option and still a ugly hack is to specify the height of the <object /> as "100vh".

Answer (score 0):

if it is in the same domain use the javascript function "contentDocument()"

try this instead : ajax

Comment: Hi There. try elaborating your solution as to why it helps OP.

Comment: @nisanth-reddy look at my new answer maybe you will understand why it is useful.

Answer (score 0):

it must be run under a server

with  "contentDocument()"

```
<object id="my-object" type="text/plain" data="newfile.txt">
</object>
<script>
    var object = document.getElementById("my-object");
    object.onload = function () {
        var objectPre = object.contentDocument.body.childNodes[0];
        object.style.height = (objectPre.offsetHeight+20) + "px";
    };
</script>
```

with ajax do a search on loading the txt file using ajax

Comment: Doing so throws the following error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'body' of null at HTMLObjectElement.object.onload

Comment: @meet-shah it must be run under a server